# Making cleveref insertions globally available

Tags: latex, auctex, variables, reftex-mode

I keep all my commonly used latex packages in one custom package, including the referencing package cleveref. However, reftex is configured to only provide insertion of cleveref referencing commands like `cref` if

```
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

is in the document itself. So I wanted to re-configure `reftex-ref-style-alist` to provide cleveref-commands without depending on the cleveref-package in the used packages in a latex document. I used the Emacs customization buffer to not have Cleveref depend on any package, yielding

```
'(reftex-ref-style-alist
   '(("Default" t
      (("\\ref" 13) ("\\Ref" 82) ("\\footref" 110) ("\\pageref" 112)))
     ("Varioref" "varioref"
      (("\\vref" 118) ("\\Vref" 86) ("\\vpageref" 103)))
     ("Fancyref" "fancyref" (("\\fref" 102) ("\\Fref" 70)))
     ("Hyperref" "hyperref" (("\\autoref" 97) ("\\autopageref" 117)))
     ("Cleveref" t
      (("\\cref" 99) ("\\Cref" 67) ("\\cpageref" 100)
       ("\\Cpageref" 68)))
     ("AMSmath" "amsmath" (("\\eqref" 101)))))
```

in my customized variables, but for whatever reason, this still doesn't lead to reftex providing the cleveref commands without cleveref called in a tex file. I also tried to put the following into my `(usepackage tex)` `:config` settings:

```
  (eval-after-load
      "latex"
    '(TeX-add-style-hook
      "cleveref"
      (lambda ()
        (if (boundp 'reftex-ref-style-alist)
            (add-to-list
             'reftex-ref-style-alist
             '("Cleveref" t
               (("\\cref" ?c) ("\\Cref" ?C) ("\\cpageref" ?d) ("\\Cpageref" ?D)))))
        (reftex-ref-style-activate "Cleveref")
        (TeX-add-symbols
         '("cref" TeX-arg-ref)
         '("Cref" TeX-arg-ref)
         '("cpageref" TeX-arg-ref)
         '("Cpageref" TeX-arg-ref)))))
```

Neither of these worked. Why? And how can I set reftex-cleveref-insertions to be globally available.

Edit:
Interestingly, if I have

```
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

in one of the .tex files in a buffer in my desktop file when I start Emacs, it seems to provide the corresponding reftex-templates globally, so in particular in files in which it is not included. However, the same isn't true if I have it in a .sty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUCTeX has a clean interface for hand-written LaTeX package files: You can write a corresponding AUCTeX style file and AUCTeX will load it when you use the package.  Say your custom package is called `custom-package.sty`, then you write a file `custom-package.el` which looks like this:

```el
(TeX-add-style-hook
 "custom-package" ; <= Adjust
 (lambda ()
   (TeX-run-style-hooks "cleveref"))
 :latex)
```

and save it under a directory available in `TeX-style-private`.  Make sure you have this in your init file as well:

```el
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

Now restart Emacs and open your .tex file.  AUCTeX should load your custom style file as well and `cleveref` should be available, also with RefTeX.